# Djange Queryset .annotate - Add 45 days to a date field

Tags: django, date, django-queryset

I want to display `my_date + 345` days using Django .annotate.

In the code below,

```
date_plus_1=ExtractYear('my_date')+1,
```

works fine to give me a the year plus one, but I want the date plus 345 days.

CODE:

```
.annotate(
    date_plus_1=ExtractYear('my_date')+1,
    #date_plus_345=('my_date' + timedelta(days=345)),
)
```

When I remove the # (in the code), my page will not generate.

After searching around, I also tried this:

```
date_plus_345=ExpressionWrapper(F('my_date') + timedelta(days=345)),
```

but that did not work either.

What is the correct way to use timedelta within .annotate?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You forgot to specify the `output_field=…` parameter of the [**`ExpressionWrapper`** expression <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#expressionwrapper-expressions):

```
from datetime import timedelta
from django.db.models import DateTimeField, ExpressionWrapper, F

MyModel.objects.annotate(
    date_plus345=ExpressionWrapper(
        F('creation_date') + timedelta(days=345),
        output_field=DateTimeField()
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks some much. That worked great. Thanks for fixing my question too. I could not figure out how to get my code chunk together before I posted.